# Additional colors in Firefox options

Tags: firefox

In Firefox → `options` → `content` → `fonts & colors` → `colors` , there is a palette with 70 predefined colors to choose from.

[image]

Is it possible to apply a different non predefined color?

Comment: Have a look in `about:config` for e.g. `browser.display.background_color`.

Comment: That is correct, thanks, but not convenient enough. As I see what I actually need is a way to change the preselected colors. It is for the settings in an addon that is using the same predefined palette.

Comment: Finally I have found that the addon has a separate about:config key. Only to locate it i had to search for a sub string of it's name and not the entire name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this addon [Color toggle](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/color-toggle/) which will enable you to use hex value of colors in additional with keyboard shortcuts to change the color scheme. There is no way to change the predefined ones, unless you recompile Firefox (I don't know if any Addon can do that).

[image: ColorToggle Screenshot]